# Дружественная функция "<<" с шаблонным классом

Tags: c++, c++14

Я написал шаблонный класс матриц произвольного размера и хочу перегрузить оператор через дружественную функцию "<<". Но получил ошибку:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, matrix<int> const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [10] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/10.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/10.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [10] Error 2
```

Мой шаблонный класс: (*matrix.h*)

```cpp
template <class T>
class matrix{
protected:
    unsigned long width;
    unsigned long height;
    vector <vector<T>>* ptr;
public:
    matrix(unsigned long val_height, unsigned long val_width): height(val_height), width(val_width){
        ptr = new vector<vector <T>> (height, vector<T> (width, 0));
    }
    ~matrix(){
        delete ptr;
    }
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& s, const matrix<T>& m);
};

template <class T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& s, const matrix<T>& m){
    for (int i = 0; i < m.height; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m.width; j++){
            s << *m.ptr[i][j];
        }
        s << endl;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Инстанцирование шаблона для целочисленного типа: (*main.cpp*)

```cpp
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    matrix<int> a(2, 2);
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Моя система и компилятор:
MacOS Mojave, clang C++14, cmake v.3.13, IDE CLion

Спасибо за Ваши ответы!

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Чтобы динамически выделить память. Исправил, но теперь вылетают ошибки: error: expected unqualified-id,  use of undeclared identifier 'ptr'

Comment: приоритет у * меньше, чем у [], поэтому нужно в скобки взять `cout << (*m.ptr)[0][0];`, а память и так выделяется в самом vector, зачем делать указатель на vector, совсем непонятно, разве чтобы вот такие ошибки получать

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Получается, что я мог это сделать таким образом:
в protected: vector<vector<T>> ptr;
Тогда как должен был бы выглядеть мой конструктор и дестркутор? Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: @ion.mion https://ideone.com/Nkd8j9

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Спасибо!